How do I eliminate a part of a filename in terminal in Ubuntu 22.04?
More specifically, I have hundreds of files of which ALL contain in their filename a sequence of eight characters between two square brackets.
Example:
160-O.Terror.Está.A.Chegar.[617229A4].mp4
I want this to become:
160-O.Terror.Está.A.Chegar.mp4
How do I eliminate everything from, and including, .[ to ] in all my mp4 files using the terminal?

Unless you need to restrict the match between brackets to exactly eight characters, this previous answer should be easily adaptable How to remove square brackets, any text inside, and space after & before the brackets?

Thank you, but I specifically asked for a solution using the TERMINAL.

Use mv, rename or whatever command line tool you prefer. If doing a single file the simple mv will achieve the result fastest, but if doing many files (esp. with complex names) I prefer rename (though it'll assume you understand the POSIX/perl type....)

Something like:
for f in *.mp4; do mv -n "$f" "${f%.[*}.${f##*.}"; done

